# Ajax call in Django to see if user already exists

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I am verifying if a user already exists when he puts his email address in the field on an onblur event. I am also using an external JS file which sends an ajax request to the specified url. However, it is not working. When I start typing in the field, it is telling me email address already exists. Am I doing it the right way?

Here is the code:

views.py

```
  def validate_stud_username(request):
       if request.is_ajax():
     username = request.GET.get('stud_email', None)
     response = {
                'is_taken': 
            User.objects.filter(username__iexact=username).exists()
            }
      return JsonResponse(response)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('login/', views.login, name="login"),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name="signup"),
    path('validate_stud_username', views.validate_stud_username, 
name='validate_stud_username'),
]
```

signup.html

```
<form action="{% url 'signup' %}" id="stud_registration_form" 
 method="POST" data-url="{% url 'validate_stud_username' %}">
 {% csrf_token %}
                           
 <input type="email" id="stud_email" style="color: black;" 
 name="stud_email" value="" placeholder=" Email" 
 autocapitalize="none" required>
 <span style="color: red;" class="error_form" id="stud_email_err"> 
 </span>

 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block login_btn" type="submit" 
 style="padding: 2% 0;"> Sign Up </button>

 </form>
```

form_validations.js

```
  $("#stud_email").blur(function () {
    $.ajax({
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      url: $("form#stud_registration_form").data("url"),

      success: function (response) {
        $("#stud_email").removeClass("valid taken");
        if (response.is_taken == true) {
          $("#stud_email").addClass("taken");
        } else {
          $("#stud_email").addClass("valid");
        }
          check_stud_email();
      },
      error: function (response) {
        console.log(response.responseJSON.errors);
      },
    });
  });

function check_stud_email() {
    var pattern = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    var email = $("#stud_email").val();

    if (pattern.test(email)) {
     $("#stud_email_err").hide();
     $("#stud_email").css("border-bottom", "2px solid #34F458");
      return false;
    } else {
      if (!$("#stud_email").val()) {
        $("#stud_email_err").html("Email cannot be blank");
      }

      if ($("#stud_email").hasClass("taken")) {
        $("#stud_email_err").html(
          "Email address already exists! Use another one or log in"
        );
      } else {
        $("#stud_email_err").html("Invalid email address");
      }
        $("#stud_email_err").show();
        $("#stud_email").css("border-bottom", "2px solid #F90A0A");
      return true;
    } 
  }
```

Comment: The first thing you need to do is debug the server response. Go to http://localhost/validate_stud_username?stud_email=test@test.com and check the result (also, when you post HTML, please post the final version from the browser's source view, not your template source)

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/Lcf5zokg/ (note that my business email address ends in `.support` and would fail your pattern check)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243960/discussion-on-question-by-alpha-ajax-call-in-django-to-see-if-user-already-exist).